# Make nautilus automatically display music tag information when a folder containing music files is opened

Tags: nautilus, music

I'm new to Ubuntu and previously been using Windows 10. A feature which I liked in Windows Explorer is that, whenever I open any folder containing music files , it automatically displays the music's tag information i.e Artist, Album, Track etc. in columns, but it switches back to Date Modified, Size etc. columns whenever any other folder not containing music files is opened. How can I get the same feature in Nautilus?